# During Install: unexpected Arabic text in Elevated Permissions Dialog … why?

Tags: macos, language

Can anybody explain this, and more importantly how to solve it? It only appears to be the dialog that comes up asking for elevated permissions when installing an application, and everything works as expected, even though the text coming up is wrong.

[image: Weird Language Issue on Installer]

I'm running OSX 10.8.4 on an iMac, language settings wise I now have only British English installed, everything else has been removed.

Running `sudo defaults read -g AppleLanguages` produces:

```
The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleLanguages) does not exist
```

Also it doesn't seem to be all installers. I've just installed a new Canon printer, and the dialog requesting elevated permissions came up as normal.

Comment: Does it happen with every installer? Does it happen anywhere else?

Comment: Only happens if an installer tries to elevate permissions, so for example if System Preferences asks for a password, that works normally. Everything else is in British English except for this dialog.

Comment: See above for updated information.

Comment: (I do NOT want to sound alarmistic, BUT...) "Type your (…) Installer (…).password to allow this" sounds somehow fishy to me. Are you sure this is a legitimate dialog? Arabic is a Right-To-Left language and this may be used to mask something.

Answer (score 2):

Mixed localizations like this have been reported fairly frequently in Mountain Lion, Arabic being the most common.  Normally it can be fixed by just going to system preferences/language & text/language and using the Edit button to remove Arabic.

Having only British English on that list may be risky, because the OS has no British English localization, so something else has to be used.  Try adding back at least English and perhaps some other languages and then restarting.  Or even adding back English and Arabic and then restarting and then remove Arabic and restart.